# Write dynamic pivot in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, pivot, pivot-table, mysql-workbench

This is my code for pivot my data. I want to convert it to dynamic..

I tried and it showing error..

```
SELECT  id,
     GROUP_CONCAT(
         CASE 
             WHEN question.question_name = 'Household'
             THEN answer.text
             ELSE NULL 
         END
     ) AS Household,
     GROUP_CONCAT(
         CASE 
             WHEN question.question_name = 'Dependents' 
             THEN answer.text
             ELSE NULL 
         END
     ) AS Dependents,
     GROUP_CONCAT(
         CASE 
             WHEN question.question_name = 'Generation'
             THEN answer.text
            ELSE NULL 
         END
     ) AS Generation
   
FROM user_answers
inner join answer on user_answers.answer_id=answer.answer_id
inner join question on answer.question_id=question.question_id
GROUP BY id
```

the code is working.. I want to convert it into dynamic conversion. I tried. but not working

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(
      'case when question.question_name = ''',
      question.question_name,
      ''' then answer.text ELSE 0  end) AS `',
      question_name, '`'
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  answer
inner join question on answer.question_id=question.question_id;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT id, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM user_answers
                    inner join answer on user_answers.answer_id=answer.answer_id
                    inner join question on answer.question_id=question.question_id
                    GROUP BY id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

showing the error

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql  Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS `Dependents`,case when question.question_name = 'Dependents' then answer.te' at line 1    0.000 sec
```

Comment: Please dont spam TAGS, they are there to gather the correct audience for your question, not an angry mob

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in this blog will generate the desired query and then execute it:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pivot

A Stored Procedure must be used -- that is what was causing the error you got.